# How to best make filtering in React without having a full blown backend

Tags: reactjs, filter

Good day, I am learning React and I am now trying to make a little project of my own. The project is nothing fancy, it will be a cooking website. However, I was not able to find a free API for recipes, that suited what I was trying to do, so in the end I managed to obtain a JSON file that contains all the recipes and their properties (so classical array of objects). So I created bare bones back end that basically just ships all of this recipes when I call it (id still like to mimic that I am calling some API). I call the API and save the result into state and that is all fine and well. I want to have some filtering capabilities in the app (some checkboxes and also some search bar). I've been through a lot of stuff that I could find online, but I cannot seem to find some elegant way of doing what I need. The filtering mostly relies on backend filtering. This is cool, but I am just learning the front end and I think trying to implement this on the backend is going to send me down a rabbit hole where I will spend a lot of time on this and the point is to improve my front end skills. I can make the filtering work, but it is frankly all a bit clunky and I am wondering if I am going in the right direction. The reason it does not feel so good to me, is that I am kind of forced to make copies of the state (because I always need to keep the original entire list of recipes). So application would run with entire state (full list) if no filters are engaged and it would render some filtered state if filters are engaged. To show you what I mean

```
    const shownRecipes =
        filters.Categories.length===0 && filters.Cousines.length===0
            ? recipes
            : recipes.filter((recipe: IRecipe) => {
                  if (filters.Categories?.length> 0 && filters.Cousines.length>0) {
                      return (
                          filters.Categories.includes(recipe.strCategory) &&
                          filters.Cousines.includes(recipe.strArea)
                      );
                  } else if (filters.Categories.length > 0)
                      {return filters.Categories.includes(recipe.strCategory)}
                  else if (filters.Cousines)
                      {return filters.Cousines.includes(recipe.strArea)};
              });
```

So now for example, if I want to use search bar to search just through shown recipes, it gets complicated and it feels like it should not be so complicated.

Question:
What is the best way to make filtering only on the front end side when you load "entire state" in the app startup without making various state copies? Or for it to work in elegant way, I would need to use something like Redux and useSelector hook?

Tried going through various tutorials and also previous answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? You don't create a new state here

Comment: Thank you for the interest in this subject. This is the code for two checkbox drop down menus, but I also want to add a search bar and for it to filter through the filtered recipes. So this leads me in the way where I would have to have another filtered state and now to filter through that state from the search bar. Again, I am no expert, so advice is very welcome. Hypothetically, if you were making such app, would you do it in the way I did it above?